# Full text 'in boolean mode' usage in mysql

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

Does mysql require any configuration settings to use 'in boolean mode' in full text AGAINST() function ?

Comment: No. There is no configuration involved. Would you mind telling us what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am using full text indexing on a data which is text type. It works fine when I declare the full word like AGAINST('test'). But when I try to use it in a way we use LIKE operator, it shows error. For example it does not work when I write AGAINST('tes') or AGAINST('tes*', in boolean mode). Sorry for my bad english

Comment: There is no comma in `AGAINST`. Try `MATCH (col1, col2) AGAINST ('tes' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`.

Comment: thanks bro @BennoZeeman ......u made my day..was struggling with it for a long time

Comment: I'll add it as an answer for future purposes. You may accept it as an answer if you think it's the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax for `MATCH (...) AGAINST (...)` with `BOOLEAN MODE` is:

```
MATCH (col1, col2) AGAINST ('tes' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

[dev.mysql.com/...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html)